# Connecting laser scanner and pose messages

Tags: ros, pose, messages, laserscan, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to connect laser scanner and pose messages considering I have underlying timestamp? It is by using TF? Do I need to code explicitly in my source code or just by configure TF in rviz? My goal is actually to build a point cloud using these 2 messages.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11822/connecting-laser-scanner-and-pose-messages/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-11-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS contains functionality for converting LaserScans into PointClouds. Those functions are located in the [laser_geometry](http://www.ros.org/wiki/laser_geometry) package. The function `transformLaserScanToPointCloud()` takes in a LaserScan, a tfListener, and a desired frame_id and converts that LaserScan into a PointCloud in that frame.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3